# mlogit.data in R - error in 'row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("

Tags: r, mlogit

I am trying to setup my data for the mlogit-package in R, but somehow seem to run into trouble.

My data-frame is called choice2, and it looks like this:

```
id choice_id mode.ids choice weightloss adveffect inj tab infreq_1 infreq_3 cost
1        x1        A      0        3.5         0   1   0        1        0  550
1        x1        B      0       10.0         1   0   1        0        1   90
1        x1        C      1        0.0         0   0   0        0        0    0
1       x10        A      0        6.0         0   1   0        0        1   50
1       x10        B      0        3.5         1   0   1        1        0  165
1       x10        C      1        0.0         0   0   0        0        0    0
1       x11        A      0        2.0         1   1   0        0        1  165
1       x11        B      1        3.5         0   0   1        1        0   90
1       x11        C      0        0.0         0   0   0        0        0    0
1       x12        A      0       10.0         1   1   0        0        1  550
```

I setup my data for the mlogit-package in R by running the following command:

```
require(mlogit)
CLOGIT <- mlogit.data(choice2,
                  choice = "choice",
                  shape = c("long"),
                  id.var = "id",
                  alt.var = "mode.ids",
                  varying = 5:11,
                  chid.var = "choice_id",
)
```

However, this results in the following error-message:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x1.A", "x1.B", "x1.C",  : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘x1.A’, ‘x1.B’, ‘x1.C’, ‘x10.A’, ‘x10.B’, ‘x10.C’, ‘x11.A’, ‘x11.B’, ‘x11.C’, ‘x12.A’, ‘x12.B’, ‘x12.C’, ‘x13.A’, ‘x13.B’, ‘x13.C’, ‘x2.A’, ‘x2.B’, ‘x2.C’, ‘x3.A’, ‘x3.B’, ‘x3.C’, ‘x4.A’, ‘x4.B’, ‘x4.C’, ‘x5.A’, ‘x5.B’, ‘x5.C’, ‘x6.A’, ‘x6.B’, ‘x6.C’, ‘x7.A’, ‘x7.B’, ‘x7.C’, ‘x8.A’, ‘x8.B’, ‘x8.C’, ‘x9.A’, ‘x9.B’, ‘x9.C’
```

Choice2 can be desciribed by the following:

```
> str(choice2)
'data.frame':   7722 obs. of  11 variables:
$ id        : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ choice_id : Factor w/ 13 levels "x1","x10","x11",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
$ mode.ids  : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
$ choice    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
$ weightloss: num  3.5 10 0 6 3.5 0 2 3.5 0 10 ...
$ adveffect : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 ...
$ inj       : int  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
$ tab       : int  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
$ infreq_1  : int  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 ...
$ infreq_3  : int  0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
$ cost      : int  550 90 0 50 165 0 165 90 0 550 ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I have sought into the help-documentation of mlogit, and sought into similar topics here on stackowerflow without succes :)

All the best, 
Henrik

Comment: Bump! I really need help on this one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that your `choice_id` variable indexes the choice occasion for each respondent. However, that is not what the `chid` variable (technically a component of an attribute) in an `mlogit.data` object represents. The `chid` variable in an `mlogit.data` object represents choice occasions across the whole dataset. So if respondents 1 and 2 were presented with 13 choice tasks each, then the `chid` variable will be `1:26`, rather than `rep(1:13,2)`. That's why you're getting the non-unique row names error, because `mlogit.data` generates the row names as an interaction between the `chid` variable and the alternative variable.

But you don't need to worry about the `chid` variable, because `mlogit.data` will take care of it for you. Simply take out the `chid.var` argument in your call to `mlogit.data`, and you won't receive the error.

```
> require(mlogit)
> choice2 = data.frame(id = rep(1:2, each = 9),
+                      choice_id = rep(rep(1:3, each = 3), times = 2),
+                      mode.ids = rep(LETTERS[1:3], times = 6),
+                      choice = rep(c(0,0,1), times = 6),
+                      inj = runif(18) > 0.5)
> 
> # Causes error because chid.var is specified
> mlogit.data(choice2,
+             choice = 'choice',
+             shape = 'long',
+             id.var = 'id',
+             alt.var = 'mode.ids',
+             varying = 5,
+             chid.var = 'choice_id')
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = c("1.A", "1.B", "1.C",  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘1.A’, ‘1.B’, ‘1.C’, ‘2.A’, ‘2.B’, ‘2.C’, ‘3.A’, ‘3.B’, ‘3.C’ 
> 
> # Does not cause error because chid.var is not specified
> mlogit.data(choice2,
+             choice = 'choice',
+             shape = 'long',
+             id.var = 'id',
+             alt.var = 'mode.ids',
+             varying = 5)
    id choice_id mode.ids choice   inj
1.A  1         1        A  FALSE  TRUE
1.B  1         1        B  FALSE  TRUE
1.C  1         1        C   TRUE FALSE
2.A  1         2        A  FALSE FALSE
2.B  1         2        B  FALSE  TRUE
2.C  1         2        C   TRUE FALSE
3.A  1         3        A  FALSE FALSE
3.B  1         3        B  FALSE FALSE
3.C  1         3        C   TRUE  TRUE
4.A  2         1        A  FALSE  TRUE
4.B  2         1        B  FALSE FALSE
4.C  2         1        C   TRUE FALSE
5.A  2         2        A  FALSE FALSE
5.B  2         2        B  FALSE  TRUE
5.C  2         2        C   TRUE FALSE
6.A  2         3        A  FALSE  TRUE
6.B  2         3        B  FALSE FALSE
6.C  2         3        C   TRUE  TRUE
```